# My Bootstrap Navbar Doesn't Open Again After Collapsing

Tags: html, css

On mobile, my app has a navbar that collapses the menu choices. However, when I select an option from the menu and then try to open the navbar again, it will quickly open before closing immediately. It does not open properly and eventually gets stuck. Here is my code for site layout:

```
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <title>@Page.Title</title>
                    <!--<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

                    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


                    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
                    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
                    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
                    <script src="~/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>

                    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <script src="js/shieldui-all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


                    <script type="text/javascript">

                        jQuery(function ($) {
                            $("#datepicker").shieldDatePicker({

                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $('#Home_Ph').shieldMaskedTextBox({
                                mask: "(000) 000-0000"
                            });
                            $('#Cell_Ph').shieldMaskedTextBox({
                                mask: "(000) 000-0000"
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#DL_or_ID").shieldTextBox({
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#Name").shieldTextBox({
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#AddressNo").shieldTextBox({
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#AddrStName").shieldTextBox({
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#AddrStNameEnd").shieldTextBox({
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(function () {
                            $("#AddrUnitNumber").shieldTextBox({

                            });
                        });
                    </script>



                    <style>
                        .container {
                            background-image: url("/Content/img/datepicker/s4.png");
                            background-position: center;
                            background-repeat: no-repeat;
                            height: 740px;
                        }

                        .top {
                            padding-top: 290px;
                        }

                        #field {
                            width: 200px;
                            line-height: 37px;
                            background-color: #f5f5f5;
                            opacity: 0.83;
                            padding: 7px;
                            margin: 0 auto;
                        }
                    </style>
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                </head>
                <body style="color:#2C537B;font-weight:normal;background-color:#f5f5f5" class="theme-light">
                    <header style="color:white;font-weight:normal;background-color:#3B414C">
                        <div class="content-wrapper" style="color:#2C537B;font-weight:bold;background-color:#143150">
                            <!--<div class="float-left" style="color:#2C537B;font-weight:bold;background-color:#3C414C">-->
                            <img src="~/Images/CDWP2.png">
                            <!-- </div>-->
                            <div class="float-right" style="color:white;font-weight:bold;background-color:#394a7e">
                                <section id="login">
                                    <!--
                                    @if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated) {
                                        <text>
                                            Hello, <a class="email" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage">@WebSecurity.CurrentUserName</a>!
                                            <form id="logoutForm" action="~/Account/Logout" method="post">
                                                @AntiForgery.GetHtml()
                                                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log out</a>
                                            </form>
                                        </text>
                                    } else {
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    }-->
                                </section>
                                <!--
                                <nav>
                                    <ul id="menu">
                                        <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="~/About">About</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </nav> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
                        <div class="navbar-brand"><font color="white">TEST</font></div>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>

                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="~/About.cshtml"><font color="white"> Home </font><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="~/test.cshtml"><font color="white"> Test1 </font></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="~/test2.cshtml"><font color="white"> Test2 </font></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="~/test3.cshtml"><font color="white"> Test3 </font></a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </nav>


                    <div id="body">
                        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                            @RenderBody()
                        </section>
                    </div>
                    <style>
                        .footer {
                            position: fixed;
                            left: 0;
                            bottom: 0;
                            width: 100%;
                            background-color: #3B4B7D;
                            color: #f5f5f5;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                    </style>


                    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
                </body>
                </html>
```

Here is the code for one of my pages with most stuff stripped out, leaving html tags and scripts:

```
            @{
                Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
                Page.Title = "Test Page";
            }

            <head>
                <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            </head>




            <style>
                .rTable {
                    display: table;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .rTableRow {
                    display: table-row;
                }

                .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
                    display: table-cell;
                    padding: 0px 0px;
                    border: none;
                    color: #f5f5f5;
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .rTableHeading {
                    display: table-header-group;
                    background-color: #ddd;
                    font-weight: normal;
                }

                .rTableFoot {
                    display: table-footer-group;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    background-color: #ddd;
                }

                .rTableBody {
                    display: table-row-group;
                }

                .sTable {
                    display: table;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .sTableRow {
                    display: table-row;
                }

                .sTableHeader {
                    display: table-cell;
                    color: #394a7e;
                    background-color: #a9cafa;
                    padding: 3px 10px;
                    border: none;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    margin: 0 auto;
                }

                .sTableHead {
                    display: table-cell;
                    color: #394a7e;
                    padding: 3px 10px;
                    border: none;
                    font-weight: normal;
                }

                .sTableCell {
                    display: table-cell;
                    color: #394a7e;
                    padding: 3px 10px;
                    border: 2px;
                    border-color: black;
                    font-weight: normal;
                }

                .sTableFoot {
                    display: table-footer-group;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    background-color: #ddd;
                }

                .sTableBody {
                    display: table-row-group;
                }
            </style>





            <html>
            <body>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

                <center><font color="#3B4B7D"><h2>Test</h2></font></center><hr />







            </body>
            </html>
```

Please help me identify the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Just place the code which calls the menu inside a file and then include it on all your pages

Comment: @hans-afrik aren't I already doing that by placing Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml"; on every page?